# cannot wrap text automatically in Jupiter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I run Jupiter lab from windows server and open it using windows edge,
However, the word cannot be wrapped automatically.

For example, generally if I type abc, then select abc, and type ', then it will be come 'abc'. But this does not happen like any other IDE/ Jupiter notebook. Now, it deletes abc and only output '....

I am not sure if there is anything wrong and how do I fix it.. I tried upgrading the entire jupiter lab, but there is no use.